# Repeat each element in array "i" times in C

Tags: c, arrays, loops, duplicates, copy

This has to be done in C.
I'm Looking for a way to take an array with elements such as:

```
a = {1,2,3}
```

and given a variable such as i, if i = 3, each element copied into a new array i times like so:

```
b = {1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,}
```

this is what I have so far:

```
for(i = 0; i < size_S-inter_seq; i++) //size of new array - times copied
{
  for(j = 0; j < size_X; j++)  //size of old array
  {
    for(k = 0; k < inter_seq; k++) //times to be copied
    {
      b[i+k] = a[j];
    }
  }
}
```

thanks

The order does matter.
Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried a series of nested loops and none of them seemed to work. Sorry if this seems like a simple problem I am a student still trying to learn C.

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking
At least, you should provide a [mcve] and explain what output you get and what you expect instead.

Comment: Show us your best attempt so far, and the output you get from it, and what's wrong with it, and we can help you fix it — that's an MCVE ([MCVE]).  Don't show us the code and all we can do is down-vote.  We don't write code for you; we will help fix honest attempts to solve a problem.

Comment: One issue is making sure you know how big the array `a` is; another issue is making sure `b` is big enough for `i` copies of `a`.  There are many ways to address the problems; we need to see what you've tried in order to calibrate what responses might help you sensibly.  At the moment, saying "`malloc()` and `free()`" would probably scare you off — yet they're a valid option for those who know what they do.  If you're on Windows and using MCVS, you have different options from if you're on Linux or Mac with GCC or Clang.

Comment: Sorry if this is a bit confusing this all being dynamically created. So its a little difficult to provide a clear example.

Comment: You missed the *complete* part of [mcve]. You're obviously asking because there is something you don't understand, so don't make assumptions about where the problem is. It can be outside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should do the trick:

```
int a[] = {1,2,3};
int i = 3;
int len = (sizeof a)/(sizeof a[0]);
int b[i*len];
for(int k=0; k<len; k++)
    for(int j=0; j<i; j++)  
        b[k*i + j] = a[k];
```

Comment: This seemed to work thanks! Sorry about all the confusion. This was my first question I asked on SO. I'll take this as learning experience and be more clear in questions and read the guidelines.

Comment: @michael Learning how to ask questions on a forum is a skill you develop as much as you're developing your programming skills.